# tkinter e Adafruit IO Why the cycle while it is not working?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, adafruit

I've recently been using python....
I cannot understand why the while loop prevents the creation of the tkinter window.

If I move the while loop before the mainloop I display the tkinter window but the loop stops.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed, RequestError

ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = "***********"
ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = "**********************"
aio = Client(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)
loop_delay = 5
temp = 25

try:
    temperature = aio.feeds('temperature')
except RequestError: 
    feed = Feed(name="temperature")
    temperature = aio.create_feed(feed)
    
def sendtemp(temp):  
    aio.send_data(temperature.key,temp) 
    data = aio.receive(temperature.key)
    print(data.value)
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title ("Thermometer")
window.geometry("300x100")
label = tk.Label(window, text = temp)
label.pack()

window.mainloop 

while True:
    sendtemp(temp)
    time.sleep(loop_delay)
```

Comment: When you look around Stack Overflow, how many questions in Italian do you see, besides your own?

Comment: Sorry you're right, thanks.

Comment: That's a lot better!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way, what do you think?

```
import tkinter as tk

from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed, RequestError

ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = "**********"
ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = "***************"

aio = Client(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)

try:
    temperature = aio.feeds('temperature')
except RequestError: 
    feed = Feed(name="temperature")
    temperature = aio.create_feed(feed)
    
class Timer:
    
     def __init__(self, parent):
         self.temp = 25
         self.label = tk.Label(text="--,- °C", font="Arial 30", width=10)
         self.label.pack()
         self.label.after(5000, self.sendtemp)

     def sendtemp(self):
         aio.send_data(temperature.key,self.temp) 
         data = aio.receive(temperature.key)
         print(data.value)
         self.label.configure(text="%i°C" % self.temp)
         self.temp +=1
         self.label.after(5000, self.sendtemp)       

if __name__ == "__main__":
     window = tk.Tk()
     window.title ("Thermometer")
     window.geometry("300x100")
     timer = Timer(window)
     window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is blocking the program. It literally does nothing but calling `sendtemp` and sleeping.

```
while True:
    sendtemp(temp)
    time.sleep(loop_delay)
```

There is no room for reacting to events on the TK window, Python is busy doing those two things.

To do actions periodically, you need to set up a timer that runs on TK's main event loop (the one you start with `.mainloop()`). This is done with [the `.after()` method](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html).

This method takes a millisecond delay and a function you want to call.

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title ("Thermometer")
window.geometry("300x100")
timer_id = None
timer_delay = 5000

def sendtemp(temp):  
    aio.send_data(temperature.key,temp) 
    data = aio.receive(temperature.key)
    print(data.value)
    if timer_id is not None:
        start_timer()

def start_timer():
    global timer_id
    timer_id = window.after(timer_delay, sendtemp)

def stop_timer():
    global timer_id
    if timer_id is not None:
        window.after_cancel(timer_id)
        timer_id = None

start_timer()
window.mainloop()
```

You could bind stopping and starting the timer to a button.

Comment: @Chris It's a bit round-about because I can't see much re-usability for the `Timer` class (re-usability is the main purpose of classes), but if it works for you it's fine. You can always improve it later.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, I added the code to read the temperature from a tmp_102 and it runs very well if you want you can see it on my instagram page raspuino. Thanks again for your help. I will need it often because I have only been using python for a few months.